# How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{n}{(2n+1)!}}$?

Tags: calculus, summation

In a calculus book I am reading I have encountered the following problem:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{n}{(2n+1)!}}$$

The hint is to use Taylor series expansion's for $e^x$. I tried to express the sum as the form $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$

But I could not find a consistent method, I always end un with different sums of factorials that does not help me solve the problem

The official solution is $$\boxed{\frac{1}{2e}}$$

The excersise is in a chapter that mixes calculus with summation, so the solution will probably include both.

Any help or hint is highly appreaciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: if you know $e^x$ is 'all factorials', how could you get 'just the odd ones'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

The Taylor series for the hyperbolic sine function $\sinh(x)$ is given by

$$\sinh(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag1$$

If we divide both sides of $(1)$ by $x$, differentiate, and set $x=1$, awe find that

$$\underbrace{\cosh(1)-\sinh(1)}_{=e^{-1}}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(2n+1)!}\tag2$$

Finally, dividing $(2)$ by $2$ yields the coveted result

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(2n+1)!}=\frac1{2e}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

We begin with the Taylor series for $e^x$ at $x=-1$.  Then, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\frac1e&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(2n)!}-\frac1{(2n+1)!}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)!-(2n)!}{(2n)!(2n+1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{(2n+1)!}\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align}$$

from which we arrive at the coveted result

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(2n+1)!}=\frac1{2e}$$

as expected!

Comment: Could you expand on step 2 of methodology 2. I do not find that easy to see the separation you did from the fraction involving $(-1)^n$ to two different fractions.

Comment: Sure.  This was a decomposition of even and odd terms.  But the odd terms are negative while the even terms are positive.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Viola. It helped my a lot to solve my problem. Also thanks for your willingness to help. Already marked it has the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $\frac{n}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{2n+1-1}{2(2n+1)!} = \frac{1}{2 (2n)!} - \frac{1}{2(2n+1)!}$

Comment: +1 That avoids any further answer. Nice job.

Comment: @FelixMarin at the end of the day it's nice to know there's something you know

Answer (score 2):

First off, this looks like the derivative of the following sum, evaluated at $x = 1$:

$\begin{align*}
   &\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x^n}{(2 n + 1)!}
\end{align*}$

Trouble is that we get only odd terms of something like:

$\begin{align*}
   e^{x^{1/2}}
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^{n/2}}{n!}
\end{align*}$

Now if:

$\begin{align*}
   f(z)
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
\end{align*}$

then:

$\begin{align*}
   \frac{f(z) + f(-z)}{2}
      &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{2 n} z^{2 n} \\
   \frac{f(z) - f(-z)}{2}
      &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{2 n + 1} z^{2 n + 1}
\end{align*}$

So your sum is:

$\begin{align*}
  S(x)
     &= x^{1/2} \frac{e^{x/2} - e^{-x/2}}{2} \\
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{(2 n + 1)!}
\end{align*}$

What is left is routine:

$\begin{align*}
   S'(1)
     &= \frac{e}{2} 
\end{align*}$

The manipulations are valid inside the region of convergence of the series for $e^x$, i.e., all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%5E%281%2F2%29%29*%28e%5E%28x%2F2%29-e%5E%28-x%2F2%29%29%2F2%29%27+at+x%3D1) gives $S'(1)=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}$...

Comment: This is not the correct result.  For $x<0$, the $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined on the reals.  And $e^{\sqrt z}$ has no Taylor series representation for $z\in \mathbb{C}$?  If a function has a Taylor series, it is analytic.  $e^{\sqrt z}$ is not analytic.

Comment: I think your answer does not match the one given by the book. The method proposed by Mark Viola fits better the level I am expected. But thank you for you help and time!